# Sending String over Serial Comm UART-8250 x8086 [ASSEMBLY]

Tags: assembly, serial-port, masm, x86-16, serial-communication

=I'm using DOSBOX, [TASM OR MASM doesn't make a difference for my code].

Ok, so I'm working on some serial comm code game, and it actually has that part that asks for your "User Name", and wait till the other player enter his name as well, so it takes you to the main menu.

Problem here, I can't send the "PlayerName" to the other PC, and receive it as "PartnerName".

This is a part of my Code :

```
Welcome proc   ;Welcome Screen !

mov al,03h
mov ah,00
int 10h

mov ah,02h
mov dh,10d
mov dl,20d
mov bh,00d
int 10h

mov ah,09h
lea dx,WelcomeMsg
int 21h

mov dh,11   ;Row number
mov dl,28   ;Column number
mov bh,0
mov ah,2
int 10h

;Reading PlayerName
mov ah,0ah
lea dx,PlayerName
int 21h

;Adding $ at the end, so we can print it later
mov bx,00
mov bl,PlayerName[1]
mov PlayerName[bx+2],'$'



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CHECKING FOR NAME;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; SendingName:  ;Sending Player Name
; mov dx,3fdh
; in al,dx
; test al,01000000b
; jnz SendNameDone
; jmp SendingName
; SendNameDone:
; lea ax,[PlayerName]
; mov dx,3f8h   
; out dx,ax


; ReceivingName:  ;Receiving PLayer Name
; mov dx,3fdh
; in al,dx
; test al,00000001b
; jnz ReceiveNameDone
; jmp ReceivingName   ;This will occur if nothing is received.
; ReceiveNameDone:
; mov dx,3f8h
; in ax,dx
; mov si,ax
; mov di,OFFSET PartnerName
; mov cx,15
; movsb

; mov dh,1   ;Row number
; mov dl,1   ;Column number
; mov bh,0
; mov ah,2
; int 10h

; mov ah,09h
; lea dx,PartnerName
; int 21h

; mov ah,01h
; int 21h



;Confirm Message
mov dh,13   ;Row number
mov dl,18   ;Column number
mov bh,0
mov ah,2
int 10h

mov ah,09h
lea dx,WelcomeMsg2
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h

ret
Welcome endp
```

And if you're confused, there's a part of my DataSegment:

```
WelcomeMsg db 'Welcome, Please Enter Your Name: $'
WelcomeMsg2 db 'Please Press Any Key To Continue!$'
```

Problem here, that my "Commented-Part" -I know it's wrong- does seem to get into an infinite loop.

If you could help and tell me how can I send the "PlayerName" over the serial Comm and receive it as "PartnerName" .. I would be very thankful !

Answer (score 0):

First clear the Divisor Latch Access Bit in order to use the Transmitter Holding Register.

```
mov dx,03FBh        ;Line Control Register
in al,dx
and al,0111_1111b   ;Set DLAB=0
out dx,al
```

Transmit a byte at a time checking if the Transmitter Holding Register is empty.

```
mov si,PlayerName+2 ;Send name including terminating $ character
SendingName:        ;Sending Player Name
mov dx,03FDh        ;Line Status Register
in al,dx
test al,0010_0000b  ;Use bit 5 to see if THR is empty
jz SendingName
lodsb
mov dx,03F8h        ;Transmitter Holding Register   
out dx,al
cmp al,"$"
jne SendingName
```